# Manage connectivity of apps to internet of Sim-card vs. wifi

Tags: applications, wi-fi, internet, sim-card, application-manager

I have a Redmi note 8 android smart-phone,
If I use Wifi then all the applications connect to the internet, But in Simcard, some of the applications are not able to connect to the internet.

For instance, in sim-card internet, some apps like Telegram or Whatsapp connect to the internet easily, but my Chrome browser or google map does not connect to the internet and says you are offline and there is no connectivity.

I'm wondering if there is a place in android or specifically in redmi note 8 which manages how application connectivity.

Thanks

Comment: To identify the cause you ca test a different SIM card in your Redmi phone, or test the SIM card in a different device. Then you will see if the cause is the phone or your mobile network provider.

Answer (score 1):

1. Turn off any power saving mode or data saving mode. If u have limited the data per month or per day, then turn that off.
2. Run an Internet Speedtest from the sim card data. If you are having trouble run Speedtest may be there's an issue, so try that sim on another phone and check.
3. I think MIUI has an option for turning on/off mobile data used by app. You can find it in App Management (from settings) for a particular app.